# DELETE From table Group By

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

SQL query:

```
`SELECT * FROM `adl_auth_user` WHERE `user_id` = 1919`
```

Result is

```
id  user_id     type_id     type       auth_    role_id     
66428   1919     1                97    103     6

66429   1919    1                 97    104     6

66430   1919    1                 97    105     6

66431   1919    1                 97    106     6
```

When I Add Group By

```
SELECT * FROM `adl_auth_user` WHERE `user_id` = 1919 group by type,type_id
```

Result is

```
id  user_id     type_id     type    auth_item_id    role_id     

66428   1919    1   97                103             6
```

I dont need all Details with query

```
`SELECT * FROM `adl_auth_user` WHERE `user_id` = 1919` (its simple)
```

How can i delete table details of following

```
SELECT * FROM `adl_auth_user` WHERE `user_id` = 1919 group by type,type_id
```

**Note : All details are edited format ...**

Comment: you are using group by in improper way  .. the use of group by without aggregation function (as  min, max .. ) is deprecated in SQL .. in most  database don't work and where work the result for not  group by column is impredictable  .. so .. you should use DISTINCT in select and not group by clause

Comment: i got the answer in select ... i need a query to delete the selected details

Comment: you have the wrong answer in select  ..  if you want i can post an asnwer  for delete but you could delete the worng row....... you are using group by in wrong  way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query:

```
DELETE adl_auth_user
FROM adl_auth_user
LEFT JOIN adl_auth_user t2 
   ON adl_auth_user.type_id = t2.type_id AND
      adl_auth_user.type = t2.type AND
      adl_auth_user.id > t2.id
WHERE adl_auth_user.user_id = 1919 AND t2.id IS NOT NULL
```

deletes all records having the same `type_id` and `type` values except from the one having the *smallest* `id` value.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/485dd84/1)

Comment: 40 rows deleted. (Query took 2.9477 sec)  .... i  need to only one row that found by group by

Comment: @Rinshantechintl The query is supposed to delete *all* rows *but* one. What actually happened in your case?

Comment: @Rinshantechintl You don't need to add `GROUP BY` to the query. It is already delete all records but one.